# Plain code chunks for R input in knitr output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

##### Goal

In an R/Markdown document that I want to convert to LaTeX I want to set `knitr` options so that the entire document uses plain code chunks for all code inputs by default. Thus, for a .Rmd document with

````
```{r}
x <- 1 + 1
```
````

I want to obtain the output

````
```
x <- 1 + 1
```
````

##### Using the highlight option

I had hoped that the `highlight=FALSE` option could be used for this but this generates text-chunks rather than plain chunks. More precisely, for the simple example above, `knit()` produces an R-chunk by default (i.e., with `highlight = TRUE`):

````
```r
x <- 1 + 1
```
````

After setting `knitr::opts_chunk$set(highlight = FALSE)` a text-chunk is produced:

````
```text
x <- 1 + 1
```
````

But what I would like to have a plain chunk without any special language, see above.

##### Combination with lang option

I can obtain what I want via

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(highlight = TRUE, lang = "")
```

Thus, I do enable highlighting but set the `lang` to an empty string. This indeed yields the plain code I want to have.

There is at least one disadvantage, though (apart from the rather hacky feel of this solution). Namely, if in the same document I do want to enable highlighting in the options of one specific chunk, I have to set `lang = "r"` now instead of `highlight = TRUE`, e.g.,

````
```{r, lang="r"}
x <- 1 + 1
```
````

So I wonder whether there is a better solution for this?

##### Background

In older versions of `pandoc` (I tried 2.9.x) text-chunks were converted to `{verbatim}` code chunks in LaTeX output.

However, more recent versions of `pandoc` (I tried 2.17.x) text-chunks are converted to `{Shaded}` instead and only plain chunks are converted to `{verbatim}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another hacky solution is (I don't even dare to explain it):

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_hooks$set(highlight = function(options) {
  if (!options$highlight) {
    options$highlight = TRUE
    options$lang = ''
  }
  options
})

knitr::opts_chunk$set(highlight = FALSE)
```

```{r}
1 + 1
```

```{r, highlight=TRUE}
2 + 2
```
````

The language name `text` when `highlight = FALSE` is currently hard-coded in **knitr**, so you cannot change it: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/907184f82/R/hooks-md.R#L171 I'm open to making it configurable, but I'm not sure how (I hope not to add a new chunk option for setting the language in the case of `highlight = FALSE`).

Comment: Thanks, Yihui. Your solution is still hacky but a lot better than mine because it better hides the actual highlight handling from the end user. I think this should be good enough for the cases where I need this (in the `exams` pkg). So far it works smoothly. I had seen that `text` is hard-coded in the code and also didn't see an elegant way to making this configurable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you want, but does this in the yaml header help?

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    theme: null
    highlight: null
---
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, the YAML does not affect the Markdown output from `knit()`, I think, but only how it is eventually rendered in HTML. I was looking for a way to obtain plain code chunks directly in the Markdown output from `knit()`.